# ntpd logging debug to ntpd.log

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

using ntpd 4.2.6p5  on redhat 6.5

How do I configure /etc/ntp.conf to generate debug messages to logfile?

in /etc/ntp.conf I have

logfile  /var/log/ntpd.log

but that only does very basic entries.

Using '-d' outputs debug messages to the console, but not to the logfile.

I suppose I can use '2&>1 | tee', but that's kind of clumsy; be better to do it in the ntp.conf I think.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the [ntp.org](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-config.htm#AEN2891) FAQ:

**How can I configure the amount of logging information?**

When starting to run xntpd you should have a more verbose logging than set up by default. Before you go into the details, you might start with the following line:

```
logconfig =syncevents +peerevents +sysevents +allclock
```

When absolutely clueless of what's going on, you might enable full logging (Make sure your /etc/syslog.conf captures all these messages):

```
logconfig =all
```